# send variable between HTML pages (AngularJS)

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to do a simple thing with AngularJS and Bootstrap 3. I'm learning now and I tried to do this and I searched and I can't find any conclusion.

I have an HTML page with 3 different buttons. Each buttons redirect us to another page that is the same. I want to send to this page a different value depending on which button I used.

I read this thread [Angular.js pass value from select to another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115531/angular-js-pass-value-from-select-to-another-view)

But I'm not sure if this is the best way.

```
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li ui-route="/signup/role1">
        <a href="#!/signup/role1"><button class="btn btn-default">FooText</button></a>
    </li>
    <li ui-route="/signup/role2">
        <a href="#!/signup/role2"><button class="btn btn-default">FooText</button></a>
    </li>
    <li ui-route="/signup/role3">
        <a href="#!/signup/role3"><button class="btn btn-default">FooText</button></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Thank you to everybody

Comment: What does your .js look like?  Also, why are you using #! in the href and ui-route in the <li>?  Take a look at Angular's docs - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route and then also check out ui-router although that might be a little too much at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Now I'm studying a complete stack (mean.js) and there are several things that I don't dominate. I will study your link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this is the recommanded way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25115613/1398979). Pass the value in param and extract param on another page.

**[Other way](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#constant)** is to create const but i wont recommend you this if you need to do this process many time and i think its short of hack to use const for this process.